# how to replace numbers on X axis by dates when using plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to present the x lab as date not numbers.
if you,for instance , plot:

```
 f=c(2,1,5,4,8,9,5,2,1,4,7)
 plot(f)
```

you would get on the x axis numbers range according to how many values we have.
How can I set for example my first value as 04/01/2012 and  the second value to be 05/01/2012 and so on and then present them on x axis as date not numbers!!

I do not have date in my data but I know the first date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either label the axis yourself or get R to do it for you by creating a vector of dates for your observations using the `"Date"` class. Here is an example:

```
f <- c(2,1,5,4,8,9,5,2,1,4,7)
dates <- seq(as.Date("04/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
             by = "days", length = length(f))

plot(dates, f)
```

`dates` ends up being:

```
> dates
 [1] "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08"
 [6] "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10" "2012-01-11" "2012-01-12" "2012-01-13"
[11] "2012-01-14"
```

and the plot looks like this:

[image]

If you need more control and what the labels exactly as you have them, you need to suppress drawing the x-axis and then add it manually using `axis.Date`, e.g.

```
plot(dates, f, xaxt = "n")
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

which produces

[image]

You may also want to rotate the axis labels there, say by using `las = 2`.

See `?axis.Date`, `?strftime` and `?as.Date` for further details.

### Finer control over the placement of labels using `axis.Date`

To override the default heuristic for tick placement, specify the locations for the ticks using the `at` argument. For example, with a longer date sequence of 700 days we might place labels at the start of each month:

```
set.seed(53)
f <- rnorm(700, 2)
dates <- seq(as.Date("04/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
             by = "days", length = length(f))
head(f)
```

The plotting is slightly more involved but not much

```
op <- par(mar = c(7,4,4,2) + 0.1) ## more space for the labels
plot(dates, f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE)
labDates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), tail(dates, 1),
                by = "months")
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, at = labDates, format = "%b %y", las = 2)
title(ylab = "f") ## draw the axis labels
title(xlab = "dates", line = 5) ## push this one down a bit in larger margin
par(op) ## reset margin
```

This results in:

[image]

You can vary this theme, e.g. label every other month, minor tick for other months

```
op <- par(mar = c(7,4,4,2) + 0.1) ## more space for the labels
plot(dates, f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE)
labDates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), tail(dates, 1),
                by = "2 months")
## new dates for minor ticks
minor <- seq(as.Date("01/02/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), tail(dates, 1),
             by = "2 months")
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, at = labDates, format = "%b %y", las = 2)
## add minor ticks with no labels, shorter tick length
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, at = minor, labels = FALSE, tcl = -0.25)
title(ylab = "f") ## draw the axis labels
title(xlab = "dates", line = 5) ## push this one down a bit in larger margin
par(op) ## reset margin
```

which results in

[image]

The point is, if you don't like the defaults, you have *full* control over where the axis *is* labelled, simply by creating the vector of dates for the locations of the labels/tick marks you desire.

Comment: @ZadSim There is now way you will fit 700 labels on the x-axis unless you make the plot window very big or the labels very small. Why do you want to label each day? Read `?axis.Date` as that allows you to control where the labels are placed etc. (Hint: see the `at` argument.)

Comment: @ZadSim The behaviour you are seeing is just R's in built way of simplifying the plot - if there is only one tick mark then R decided via some heuristics that only that one tick mark was needed. You can override this by specifying where you want the ticks (and labels) using the `at` argument to `axis.Date`. See the Examples section of `?axis.Date` as that show how to use `at`.

Comment: @ZadSim It does that for example if the dates span a period either side of the start of a year. It is a simple heuristic and as `?axis.Date` says, it can be overridden. If you want to label the start of each month. I'm not sure if you still don't know how to do this or not; but I'll update the example to include something on this. Next time, be more specific in your question about the actual problem size even if you use a small example to illustrate.